# Rust: Where do I find the necessary dependencies for examples in a crate (here espc. druid)?

Tags: rust

I am very new to rust and wanted to work through some examples to get a better understanding.
I learned that cargo executes examples similar to a normal app and if there are additional dependencies which are not covered by the crate the examples are written for, there is a region in the TOML where these dependencies may be defined.

druid gives a lot of nice examples which do run when I start them with e.g.

`cargo run --example text`

Then I get a little window which shows a text and the display can be modified with some radio buttons.
But when I start a new project on my own with cargo, put druid into dependencies and copy the source from the example into main.rs this does not compile.
So what do have to change to get the example running as main?

Michael

The code can be found under
[text.rs](https://github.com/linebender/druid/blob/master/druid/examples/text.rs)

My toml looks like this:

```
[package] name = "test-text" 
version = "0.1.0" 
authors = ["michael.heisler"] 
edition = "2018" 

[dependencies] 
druid="0.6"
```

and the first error from a full bunch is:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import druid::piet::TextStorage-->src\main.rs:17:42  
17 use druid::piet::{PietTextLayoutBuilder, TextStorage as PietTextStorage}; 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no TextStorage in piet
```

Comment: Please share your code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: But my problem ist, that everything works fine, if started from the crate with the cargo run command, but not as standalone application. I guess, something is missing in the dependencies, but I do not find what

Answer (score 1):

Still I would like to know how I find the differences, but with

> druid = { git = "https://github.com/linebender/druid.git" }

in the dependencies instead of

> druid = "0.6"

the application is working